# Style files changes not taking effect

Tags: html, css

I'm building a movies site using an api.

Whe I link the css styles nothing appears to be working. Not even background color. Also i'm trying to add flex also that one is not working. Is there some problem in the linking?

It's my first question on this site and i'm still learning html and css.

```css
@import url('https://googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400&display=swap');

:root {
  --primary-color;
  #22254b;
  --secondary-color;
  #373b69;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: purple;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.search {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.search :placeholder {
  color: #7378c5;
}

.search :focus {
  outline: none;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.movie {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.movie img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details that also includes the necessary HTML markup to reproduce the issue. Then show your file structure and the head element of your HTML file. The issue can't be reproduced with the informations you provided.

Comment: Can you confirm that the CSS file is being loaded in the Network Dev Tools tab?

Comment: Have you attached your external css file properly? On windows, you might need dot before the path like "./yourCssFile.css" or "./yourCssFolder/yourCssFile.css"

Comment: Thankyou for the comments. I had to add quotes because it was not allowing me to post.

Comment: Yes there was problem in the CSS file linking and div too.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to include a stylesheet:

Approach 1, using `@import`:

```
<style>
    @import url("./path/to/styles.css")
</style>
```

If you are using `@import` make sure that it's at the top of the style block.

Approach 2, using `<link />`:

```
<head>
    <link href="./path/to/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Thankyou when when i add <style> tags it gives me error.